# How to unsubscribe from pubnub channel Python SDK

Tags: python, pubnub

I'm using pubnub with python SDK.
I have some testing environment written in python and I'm trying to write python code to add pubnub client subscribe to channel and unsubscribe. In the server I'm checking that the server gets join and leave messages (I'm using presence channel).

The problem is that when the thread dies I don't get leave message and I don't see any unsubscribe call in the python code to do explicit unsubscribe.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

My code looks something like this:

```
    def main(user_id,channel_name):
        t = Thread(target=rt_subscribe,args=(user_id,channel_name))

    def rt_subscribe(user_id,channel_name):
        def get_message(msg):
            print 'got message: %s' % msg
            return True

        pb = Pubnub(publish_key=PUBLISH_KEY, 
                  subscribe_key=SUBSCRIBE_KEY, 
                  pres_uuid=user_id,
                  ssl_on=False)
        pb.subscribe({
                   'channel'  : channel_name,
                   'callback' : get_message 
                })
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547804/cannot-unsubscribe-with-pubnub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PubNub Python SDK Unsubscribe

There are several things to consider here and the first is using the correct SDK for the job as PubNub has 3 Python SDK options available.  Also you can invoke a `Leave Event` forcefully using a simple REST call.  But first, if you want to unsubscribe via Python, you may consider using our **Python Twisted** SDK.

> [GitHub Repository for PubNub Python Twisted SDK](https://github.com/pubnub/python/tree/master/python-twisted) - Download Now

You'll issue subscribe and unsubscribe as follows:

```
pubnub.subscribe({ 'channel' : chan, 'callback' : receive_processor })
pubnub.unsubscribe({ 'channel' : chan })
```

Yes.  It's that simple.  :-)

## PubNub Force Leave Event on Presence

You can issue a REST call in the following format to force a leave event on a channel.

```
https://pubsub.pubnub.com/v2/presence/sub_key/YOUR_SUB_KEY/channel/YOUR_CHANNEL/leave?uuid=YOUR_USER_UUID
```

Comment: @eran, we also have a new unified Python SDK coming out in a few weeks that will simplify this. If you'd like advanced beta access, contact us at support@pubnub.com, and we'll hook you Up!

Comment: @Geremy deluxe. yes indeed.